# How can i remove the /en after my main URL?

Tags: php, laravel

My project built with Laravel PHP

I'm trying to minify my code using CodeKit, and i'm using MAMP Pro as a local server to run my project

The problem is after minifying my code, the CodeKit app can't run my project to view it on my browser because the URL should be ( Example.com ) not ( Example.com/en )

how to get rid of /en after the main URL please?

my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

In the beginning of `routes.php`:

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);

if(in_array($locale, ['en','fr','it'])){
    app()->setLocale($locale);
}else{
    app()->setLocale('en');

    $locale = '';
}
```

Then:

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => $locale ], function(){ 
   Route::get('/demo', 'DemoController@demo')->name('demo');
   ...
})
```

`route('demo')` will return `/demo` when app locale is english, and `/<language_code>/demo` in other languages

Comment: Thanks @Aljaž Farkaš for your comment, unfortunately it doesn't work.